# Nautilus broken in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus

when i updated ubuntu 22.04 file manager nautilus uninstalled
i tryed to use:
`apt-get update && apt-get upgrade --fix-missing` but it didnt help
when i trying install:

```
~$ sudo apt install nautilus
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nautilus : Depends: nautilus-data (= 1:42.0-1ubuntu2) but 1:42.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```